# R - minimum distance from a vector of points

Tags: r

I'm newby to R. I've a vector with distances

```
dist <- c(1, 3, 5, 20, 34)
```

Is there a function that given a point d calculates the shortest distance to an existing point ?

```
distance <- sDist(7.5, dist)
```

that returns 2.5 ( 7.5 - 5 ).

Comment: you can try `min(abs(point - dist))` where point is for example `point <- 7.5`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just do `min` on the absolute value of the difference:

```
min(abs(7.5-dist))
[1] 2.5
```

Comment: thanks, looks easy, my brain is not yet thinking in R